# How do I change modifier for Tab selection with numbers in firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

On Windows my Firefox switches to the first tab when I press Ctrl+1, to the second when I press Ctrl+2, etc.
On Linux (for all distributions and firefox versions that I have tried) this is achieved by pressing Alt+1, Alt+2, etc.

However the shortcuts Alt+1 to Alt+0 are already used by my i3-config (and I want it to stay that way). How do I change these shortcuts for firefox? I didn't find anything when searching for "tab" in the about:config page.

Also this question has been asked in the Ubuntu Stackexchange site but the answer produced there ("just leave it and change your habit instead of the settings") is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice add-on you can try called KeyConfig available from [here](http://mozilla.dorando.at/).

Click on the keyconfig.xpi and install it. Then go to your firefox addons to display various keybindings offered by the addon.

Look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND5AP.png)

Click on the box shown by the arrow and choose your key combination - **CTRL + 1**.

This will change the value in the box to **CTRL+1**. Click the Apply button

Repeat for the rest of the **key_selectTab** values.

---

You can do this manually too.

Look [here](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#keys).

Comment: Works for me. However I was hoping to find a solution without having to install an Add-On for that, so I'll leave this question open for that.

Comment: I've edited the question. Have a look.